# What versions of Android are compatible with WEAR

Tags: android, wear-os, adk

Are all versions of Android compatible with WEAR devices? I am looking into their library to try and find the version that would be compatible with "com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0".

Comment: If you are using Android Studio on sdk manager you can get your answer. I think is around Android 5 or 6 you have additional libraries to download, correspondents to WEAR.

Answer (score 1):

Wear OS is compatible with android 4.4+ except Go Edition [Wear Check](https://wearos.google.com/wearcheck/)

Reference: [Wear OS Google](https://wearos.google.com/#works-on)